# MySQL multiple query

Tags: java, mysql

I want to count records of query. The problem is that the query is not constant.

I write something like this, but this is only almost good

```
select count(*) from (select * from users);
```

where the select * from users is only example

I think something about this:

```
String query = "select * from users";
String queryCount = "select count(*) from ("  + query + ")";
```

This is not correct as in mysql query they wrote an error like this:

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

What is the correct command for that?

Comment: So give the derived table an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select count(*) from (select * from users) as alias;
```

there needs to be some name for result set that is generated by the query in brackets.

Comment: thanks, this is a good answer!